# CFMail Issues since Upgrading to CF10

Tags: coldfusion, smtp, exchange-server, coldfusion-10, cfmail

Ever since upgrading to CF10, we've been having some odd issues with our automated ColdFusion emails.  The processes always functioned properly in the past, but lately we've been getting some very out of the ordinary issues which I'll describe further below.

We discover the problem usually from contacts who usually receive these emails on a daily basis with or without attachments.  We'll go to the CFMAIL directory for the corresponding server and find a slew of emails stuck in the 'Undelivr' emails.  In some cases, we can just move these emails to the Spool folder and they process fine, but in most cases they result in one of the two errors below:

### Error 1: In an email which normally does not contain a body and contains an attachment, the follow error is what we found in the logs:

```
"Error","scheduler-1","01/15/13","14:09:56",,"javax.mail.MessagingExce ption: missing body for message"
javax.mail.MessagingException: missing body for message
                at coldfusion.mail.MailImpl.createMessage(MailImpl.java:696)
                at coldfusion.mail.MailSpooler.deliver(MailSpooler.java:1295)
                at coldfusion.mail.MailSpooler.sendMail(MailSpooler.java:1197)
                at coldfusion.mail.MailSpooler.deliverFast(MailSpooler.java:1657)
                at coldfusion.mail.MailSpooler.run(MailSpooler.java:1567)
                at coldfusion.scheduling.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:211)
                at coldfusion.scheduling.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:71)
```

---

Placing these emails that have always been sent out this way in the past without an attachment in the spool directory causes it to go right back in the 'Undelivr' folder and resulting in the same error.  We ended up having to modify the email file and add random content in the body message, place it back in the spool directory, and it went through.  - Mind boggling.

### Error 2:

```
"Error","scheduler-2","02/04/13","09:08:17",,"javax.mail.MessagingExce ption: Exception reading response;   nested exception is:    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"
```

Both errors occur randomly and we have not been able to find out what causes them randomly from time to time.  All other emails go through fine, but certain emails will never go out and end up in the 'Undelivr' folder.

We are running them on Windows Server 2008 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing second error connection reset couple of week ago but that was in CF9 and with SSL only. Here is blog post if that help

http://www.isummation.com/blog/getting-javaxmailmessagingexception-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-xxxxxxx-port-465-response-1-error-in-coldfusion/

Comment: This might be helpful since we have SSL on our site and I've seen some users post some things regarding CF10 SSL issues.  I'll have to look into this.